# Is there a way to use regular expressions to match two numbers in any order while exclude other numbers?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match numbers that contains the digits 1 and 2 in any order and but that doesn't contain digits 0,3 or 4.

My results should include:

192,129,291,127,261

```
import re

exampleLine = 'prices xom 91.43.91.44.19.192,129,291,201,124,127,261'

regEx = re.findall(r'\d[1+=2][^034]',exampleLine)

print(regEx)
```

Comment: Why does your result include `9`s, a `7`, and a `6`?  I thought it was supposed to match just `2` and `1`.

Comment: @zondo: not 0 is 9, isn't it?

Comment: @zondo .. I think OP meant to get numbers whose digits include [1,2] and exclude [0,3,4]...

Comment: .... and what about 5 to 9? Are the excluded or included?

Comment: You can also use a lookahead: [`\b(?=[15-9]*2)[25-9]*1[125-9]*\b`](https://regex101.com/r/hW4hC0/1)

Comment: The numbers that I want to capture all have three digits. I want to capture all numbers that have both a 1 and 2 in them except for those numbers that have 0,3,4.  I am trying to capture numbers 125, 126,127,128,129, but the 1 and 2 can be in any order (216,712,182,291,). I am trying to exclude numbers 102,321, 142. Thank you.

Comment: Did you [try @CasimiretHippolyte's answer](https://regex101.com/r/sG5qY6/1)? It looks like what you needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Robert Jones: Trying to solve your further request...

**1.**

> 3 digit numbers range from 5-9 but, exclude duplicate numbers

```
\b([5-9])((?!\1)(?:[5-9]))((?!\1|\2)(?:[5-9]))\b
```

[See details @regex tester ►](https://regex101.com/r/bK1vY3/1)

**2.**

> Then on the reverse I would like to run a separate regex that does
>   capture all duplicate digits. 122, 515, 996

```
(?:\b(\d)(?:\1(?:(?!\1)\d))\b)|(?:\b(\d)(\d)(?:(?!\2)\3|(?:(?!\3)\2))\b)
```

It's composed from 2 alternative parts (with conditionals):

1. `(\d)(?:\1(?:(?!\1)\d))\b)` → covers **AAX** (but not AAA)
2. `(\d)(\d)(?:(?!\2)\3|(?:(?!\3)\2))` → covers **AXA** or **XAA**

[See details @regex tester ►](https://regex101.com/r/eS2pD6/1)

Comment: I am receiving an error when trying to run the Regex. regEx = re.findall(r'(?:\b(\d)(?:\1(?:(?!\1)\d))\b)|(?:\b(\d)(\d)(?:(?!\2)\3|(?:(?!\3)\2))\b',exampleLine) 
  File "C:\Python34\lib\sre_parse.py", line 710, in _parse
    raise error("unbalanced parenthesis")
sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis

Comment: I am trying to print step 1 out as one single group, but I keep getting errors. regEx3 = re.findall(r'\b[[5-9]][(?!\1)(?:[5-9])][(?!\1|\2)(?:[5-9])]\b',exampleLine)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
\b[5-9]*(?:1[15-9]*2|2[25-9]*1)[125-9]*\b
```

You need first to use word-boundaries to avoid numbers to be truncated.

Then you can use character classes to be sure that numbers use only allowed digits.

To finish, you must describe the two possible scenarios *"the 1 appears first or the 2 appears first"* using a non-capturing group and an alternation.

```
\b
[5-9]* # eventual digits until the first 1 or 2
(?:          # non-capturing group
    1[15-9]*2   # 1 is the first
  |             # OR
    2[25-9]*1   # 2 is the first
)
[125-9]*
\b
```

Comment: Thank you that worked great! Is there anyway to exclude 122 , 212, 112, 121, etc. Thank you.

Comment: @RobertJones: I think you can easily find it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

@Robert Jones: This could meet your needs:

```
\b[5-9]*(?:1[15-9]?2|2[25-9]?1)[5-9]*\b
```

@Casimir et Hippolyte: Excellently devised!

Comment: I ran into another issue. I did some research and was not able to find a solution for this last issue. I am now trying to do regex that can find 3 digit numbers range from 5-9 but, exclude duplicate numbers. Example: 567 or 675, 589 or 985. Exclude 667, 757, etc. Then on the reverse I would like to run a separate regex that does capture all duplicate digits. 122, 515, 996. Thank you.